# Resolve "Missing ; before statement" to copy cell value based on Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to copy the value of a cell depending on the date.

```
function pastespecial() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  for (var i = 2; i <= 150; i++) {

    var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();


    if (workingCell = currentDate)  {

      var spreadsheet.getRange(i, 6).activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('AB6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
     }
   }
};
```

The error

> Missing ; before statement. (line 17, file "macros")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Comparison operator is `==` or `===` not `=`(which is the assignment operator). But you can't use them for dates.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your line

```
var spreadsheet.getRange(....
```

as you did not provide a variable name in the *declaration* that began with `var`, you just wrote a *statement* (beginning with `spreadsheet.`).

As comments indicate, once you fix this issue you will need to revisit how one compares `Date` objects based on their *time* and not just the object itself.

Comment: i really don't get it, i am too stupid.... please help me. All i want is to fill column F every day with values i find with "=IMPORTHTML("https://www.terre-net.fr/meteo-agricole/previsions-10-jours/loubens/2997498"; "table"; 1)"

Comment: column F is minimum temperature, it changes every day and i want to keep a log